# Java - does reallocating a List using subList hold a reference to previously allocated memory?

Tags: java

I inherited some java code which keeps a list of items to be displayed in a GUI table. The list has a size constraint so that only the most recent 100 items are displayed. When the list size reaches the limit, the code reallocates a new list, keeping the most recent 50 items via `subList()`.

I have a concern that when this occurs, a reference may still be kept to the previously allocated list, keeping it from getting garbage collected. Can someone tell me if this is really an issue or not?

```
private List<myclass> theList= new LinkedList<myclass>();

public int addToList( myclass newitem) {

  theList.add(0, newitem);

  if (theList.size() > 100) {

    theList = new LinkedList<myclass>(theList.subList(0, 50));

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking whether `theList = theList.subList(0, 50)` keeps a reference to the old list, or whether `theList = new LinkedList<myclass>(theList.subList(0, 50))` does?

Comment: The old reference to `theList` is lost, it becomes unreachable, however, because the new `List` and the old `List` have some cross-over in references (to elements that they contain), this might prevent the old `List` from been garbage collected.  You could create a temporary `List` (of the first 50 items), clear `theList` and assign the temporary `List` to `theList` if you're really worried

Comment: ps - an easy way to see the java source code is to google "grepcode arraylist" or similar.

Comment: Since it's reassigning the new memory to 'theList', the code has given up the reference pointer to the original allocation. The assumption in the code is that the original list of 100 items is going to be garbage collected after 50 of the items have been reallocated/copied via subList().In other words, I just want to make sure that after the 'new LinkedList' is allocated, that only 50 myclass items are allocated so that the other 50 get collected.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yes, that's the concern that I have, that the unreachable elements are still being held onto. I was going to do a temporary assignment as you said, but this seemed like it might involve an extra copying cycle (which is of course would still be preferable to the memory growing...)

Answer (score 5):

> Returns a **view of the portion of this list** between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and
>   toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is
>   backed by this list, so **non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list**, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)

subList() returns a view of the original list so it does remain used. However, once you get to  `new LinkedList<myclass>(theList.subList(0, 50));`, it will make a shallow copy and you will lose the reference to the old list.

> public ArrayList(Collection c)
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
>   in the order they are returned by the collection's
>   iterator.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)

Comment: But if both lists are maintaining strong references to the same objects, will the second list become eligible for GC?  Assuming that there are no more strong references to the original list....

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think you know the answer to that :-) For garbage collection purposes, it only matters if an object is reachable from the GC roots i.e. whether something points **to** it that is itself reachable. An object (like the second list) could have references to every other object in the VM - it doesn't matter: if the object is not pointed *to* by another reachable object or a GC root then it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That's what I thought, and that's what I think the OP is stumbling over, but it's nice to have the clarification ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the new `LinkedList` instance, it will create new "nodes" to hold the contents of the `subList` call. It does not maintain a reference to the `Collection`.
This is true of all `Collection` implementations which have a constructor taking a `Collection` as an argument. The result is a shallow copy of the argument - not a maintained reference to that `Collection`.

Comment: And if both lists maintain strong references to the same elements, will the old list become eligible for GC?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Assuming that the elements themselves do not hold a reference to the list, then the fact that strong references to (some of) the elements are maintained in the newly created list will have no impact on whether the original list instance is eligible for GC. The original list will be eligible when there are no strong references.

Comment: That's what I think the OP is asking for ;)